# How to separate strings using regex?

Tags: python, string, time

I have a datetime string and, I want to separate the hour format from the minute format and then print both of them on a separate line.
Here is the code:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
ct = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
time = "12:30"
minus = datetime.strptime(time,"%H:%M") - datetime.strptime(ct,"%H:%M")
minus = datetime.strptime(str(minus),"%H:%M:%S").strftime("%H:%M")
# print(minus)
regex2 = re.compile(r'(\d)+:(\d)+')
match = regex2.search(minus)
print(match.group(0))
```

If the variable *minus* gives an output: 01:22
Then I want it 01 and 22 to be printed on different lines.

Output Should be like:

01

22

Comment: lots of that code has nothing to do with printing hour an minute on separate line.  is `minus` part of the question you want to be asking here?

Comment: Huh? What have you tried so far and what was your result? If I run your script I get an error because your "minus" value (line 6) does not match your string ("%H:%M:%S"). The error message clearly states that. So, what exactly is your question?????

Comment: i would avoid using regex for this. Theres only one variant. Just use split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need regex for that.

you can use timedelta directly:

```
from datetime import datetime

ct = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
time = "10:30"

minus = datetime.strptime(time,"%H:%M") - datetime.strptime(ct,"%H:%M")

## extract whatever values you want from this delta:
## eg:
seconds = minus.seconds
hours = minus.seconds//3600
minutes = (minus.seconds//60)%60

print(hours)
print(minutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that your script fails due to a runtime error at line 6 (which prevents any output from being generated from the regex part of the script), to capture the digits surrounding the colon, you need to put the repetition marker (i.e. the plus sign) inside the capturing markers (i.e. the parenthesis).
So revising your regex:

```py
regex2 = re.compile(r'(\d)+:(\d)+')
```

as follows:

```py
regex2 = re.compile(r'(\d+):(\d+)')
```

Will achieve that.

The second thing you need to do is print the matching groups (as opposed to the entire matched text - i.e. group(0)).
Printing the first and second matching groups is achieved as follows:

```py
print(match.group(1))
print(match.group(2))
```

The difference between your regular expression and mine was in the number of groups that would ultimately be generated on a match.
In your case (\d)+ you requested the creation of **one or more groups of a single digit**.
In my case (\d+) I am requesting the creation of **a single group containing one or more digits**. I then use this pattern twice - once on each side of the colon.

So, for input like this 01:22, you would have created 4 groups being "0", "1", "2" and "2". Whereas my regex would generate just 2 groups "01" and "22". Which I think is what you are trying to achieve.

Note that if you had input like this "0:122", your regular expression would have generated the same 4 groups ("0", "1", "2" and "2") - you would have no idea where the ":" character was unless you also captured it (the colon). In my RE, the input "0:122" would generate "0" and "122" thereby correctly informing you where the colon was (i.e. between the "0" and the "122"

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex below:

```
'([^:]+)'
```

See regex explanation here: https://regex101.com/r/EgXlcD/46

```
    import re
    from datetime import datetime
    ct = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
    time = "10:30"
    minus = datetime.strptime(time,"%H:%M") - datetime.strptime(ct,"%H:%M")
    minus = datetime.strptime(str(minus),"%H:%M:%S"
                                         "").strftime("%H:%M")
    #print(minus)
    
    matches = re.findall(r'([^:]+)',minus)
    for match in matches:
        print (match)
```